# Flask Continuous XMLHTTP Request Returns Empty Value

Tags: javascript, flask, xmlhttprequest, client-server

I am using Flask to render a HTML page. I want to pass a variable from the server to the client continuously (for the simplicity of the question, I am just passing a string).

```js
//javascript
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/stream');
xhr.send();

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText)
});
```

```py
#python
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def generate():
        while True:
            yield '1'
            sleep(1) #removing this line outputs '111...'

    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

This just logs an empty string in the console. But if I remove the `sleep(1)` it then logs `1111....` which rapidly increases in size. The preferred output is just 1.
What am I doing wrong???